# knockout js - How to do Conditional Binding on a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I've got a Knockout viewmodel populated from a variety of Mvc actions.

1. A Category is chosen from the first dropdown (say Fruit, Meat, Drinks etc).
2. A second dropdown is automatically populated from the first choice. However, there may be 2 matches for fruit (say Apples, Oranges), 2 for meat (say Beef, Lamb) and many choices for drink (several hundred).
3. My page currently displays a search box depending on the Category chosen.

I was wondering how to automatically bind the second dropdown for Fruit & Meat, or wait and do the bind from the results of the search query.

Sorry this is vague - twitchy client! Very new to KnockoutJs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you currently bound your dropdowns to the viewmodel? Can you post the code? In general you bind a dropdown to an object (i.e.: an array) in the viewmodel. As that array gets updated the dropdown gets updated. Say, your first dropdown is bound to arrayCategory and the second dropdown is bound to arraySubCategory. When ever you select a category, I'm assuming you would update the arraySubCategory object of the viewmodel. As soon as you done that the second dropdown should automatically show the new sub categories.

Comment: This articel on observableArrays (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) shows how you manipulate arrays. In essence all you have to worry about is updating the arrays and bind them at design time to the dropdowns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I probably wasn't that clear. What I'm trying to do in my viewmodel is see if the selected value = Apple -  do this, if selected value = Drinks - do something else.

Comment: Sorry, if the selected value = Fruit - do this, if selected value = Drinks - do something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you could create a method in your viewmodel which you bind to the change event of the dropdown.

Example method:

```
var myViewModel = {
    firstDropDownArray: ko.observableArray([]),
    secondDropDownArray: ko.observableArray([]),

    // Validates Selection
    validateSelection: function (item) {
        var anotherList;

        switch (item.toUpperCase()) {
            case "FRUIT":
                // Do something...
                break;
            case "DRINKS":
                // Do something else...
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
};
```

Your Dropdown can bind then to the method like this:

```
<select id="FirstDropDown" data-bind="options: myViewModel.firstDropDownArray, <any other binding options>, event: {change: myViewModel.validateSelection(currentItem)}">
</select>
```

As stated here: [event-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html),

> When calling your handler, Knockout will supply the current model
>   value as the first parameter.

I'm assuming this means the `currentItem` will be the selected item when you are calling the method.
I know in my sample code I wrote `item.toUpperCase()` but that is just assuming the item is passed as a string. This syntax obviously has to change depending on how you have declared and populated your dropdown but in essence you still should be able to write a method in your viewmodel you can bind then to the change event,..or any other event you like.

Comment: Thanks Francois, I'll have a play with this and get back to you.

Comment: Hope it helps. Depending on what you want to do in response to `Fruit` or `Drinks` you can always enhance the viewmodel with additional observable properties you change based on the selection and bind those to other controls that need to react to the change. For example, a `searchIsVisible: ko.observable(false)` and you can set that to `true` or `false` as needed. Bind `searchIsVisible` property to the `visible` binding of your search control and happy days.